# How to sort list in vertical?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this below `HTML and CSS` code to sort list in `vertical` , the output is `horizontal` sorted.

My example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tiles</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #tiles {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    #tiles li {
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #dddddd;
        font-size: 72px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="tiles">
       <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output is :

[image]

But , I want this output.

[image]

Please give me code for sort list in `vertical`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts): ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trPRV/))

```
ul {
    column-width: 380px;
    -webkit-column-width:380px;
    -moz-column-width: 380px;
    height:440px;
}

#tiles {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#tiles li {
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Note that this won't work in IE≤9.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
    #tiles {         
        list-style: none;        
        margin: 0px; 
        width:300px;
        height:200px;   
          }     
     ul   {
        column-width: 85px;
        -webkit-column-width:85px;
        -moz-column-width: 85px;
        height:60px;
         }

    #tiles li {         
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;        
        width: 50px;         
        height: 30px;         
        background-color: #dddddd;         
        font-size: 16px;         
        text-align: center;         
        vertical-align: middle;     }
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/8jw6r/)

This is shroud as your output image